# Memory breakdown based on its speed

Tags: memory, hardware

In one technical discussion the person asked me which things you look into when you buy a laptop.
Then he asked me to Sort different types of memory e.g RAM etc on the basis of speed.In simple words he wanted memory hierarchy .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Technically speaking a processor's registers are the fastest memory a computer has. The size is very small and people generally don't include those numbers when talking about a CPU.

The quickest memory in a computer that would be advertised is the memory that is directly attached to the CPU. It's called cache, and in modern processors you have 3 levels - L1, L2, and L3 - where the first level is the fastest but also the smallest (it's expensive to produce and power). Cache typically ranges from several kilobytes to a few megabytes and is typically made from SRAM.

After that there is RAM. Today's computers use DDR3 for main memory. It's much larger and cheaper than cache, and you'll find sticks upwards of 1 gigabyte in size. The most common type of RAM today is DRAM.

Lastly storage space, such as a hard drive or flash drive, is a form of memory but in general conversation it's grouped separately from the previous types of memory. E.g. you would ask how much "memory" a computer has - meaning RAM - and how much "storage" it has - meaning hard drive space.

Comment: A cache is a micro-architectural concept, not a memory type. They're usually made of SRAM if that's what you mean, but can be made with other technologies as well (DRAM, PCM, memristors...)

Comment: @Leeor I guess it's just semantics. When talking about a physical cache I believe many would consider it to be "memory" rather than a "micro-architectural concept". Wikipedia describes it: "cache is a smaller, faster memory which stores copies of the data from frequently used main memory locations" http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CPU_cache. Good point about cache being made from SRAM, I'll edit my answer.

Comment: The point is that he could be asking for a breakdown based on memory technology, or based on the memory purpose/role - the question isn't really clear, but it should be a separate breakdown.